# Method Exists doesn't detect already created keys

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get number of unique ids with given values on given columns. I decided to use `Scripting.Dictionary` for this as follow:

```
Public Function getSoldToIrr(umowy As Range, bi As Range, irr As Range) As Double
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = umowy.Rows.Count
    bi_with = 0
    irr_with = 0
    
    ifff = 0         'count how many new values
    elseifff = 0     'count how many duplicates
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If umowy(i, 1) <> "" Then
            If Not dict.Exists(umowy(i, 1)) Then                    ' if new id
                dict(umowy(i, 1)) = Array(bi(i, 1), irr(i, 1) * bi(i, 1))
                bi_with = bi_with + bi(i, 1)
                irr_with = irr_with + irr(i, 1) * bi(i, 1)          ' if bi and irr
                ifff = ifff + 1
                    
            Else                                                    ' if found duplicate id
                If dict(umowy(i, 1))(1) = 1 And bi(i, 1) = 1 Then   ' if duplicate already had 1 on bi and now has bi
                    If dict(umowy(i, 1))(2) = 0 And irr(i, 1) = 1 Then                ' if duplicate had 0 on irr but now has 1
                        irr_with = irr_with + irr(i, 1) * bi(i, 1)
                        dict(umowy(i, 1))(2) = 1
                    End If
                ElseIf dict(umowy(i, 1))(1) = 0 And bi(i, 1) = 1 Then ' if bi was 0 and now is 1
                    dict(umowy(i, 1)) = Array(bi(i, 1), irr(i, 1) * bi(i, 1))
                    bi_with = bi_with + bi(i, 1)
                    irr_with = irr_with + irr(i, 1) * bi(i, 1)
                End If
                elseifff = elseifff + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox dict.Exists(umowy(1, 1).Value)   ' returns False
    MsgBox dict.Exists(dict.Keys()(0))      ' returns True
    MsgBox umowy(1, 1) = dict.Keys()(0)     ' returns True
    MsgBox dict.Count                       ' returns 8000
    MsgBox ifff                             ' returns 8000
    MsgBox elseifff                         ' returns 0
    
    getSoldToIrr = irr_with / bi_with
    
End Function
```

`umowy` is my id and those values are strings like `18/07/KOR/2020`, `bi` and `irr` columns are binary columns. `umowy` has some duplicates but for some reason my `dict` takes duplicates as new keys and my code does not get into `Else   ' if found duplicate id`.
Also if I write `dict.Exists(umowy(1, 1).Value)` or `dict.Exists(umowy(1, 1))` I get `False`, but  `dict.Exists(dict.Keys()(0))` gives me `True` as `umowy(1, 1) = dict.Keys()(0)` and `umowy(1, 1).Value = dict.Keys()(0)`

What can be a reason of such behaviour?

Comment: 1. Please, replace `dict(umowy(i, 1)) = Array(bi(i, 1), irr(i, 1) * bi(i, 1))` with `dict.add umowy(i, 1), Array(bi(i, 1), irr(i, 1) * bi(i, 1))`. This is the normal way of a new key adding. 2. It is a well known issue that you can change any object of a dictionary item, **except an array**. You should load a new array with the existing item one, modify it and then realocate. 3. If correctly created keys, what you say about `.Exists` error cannot happen... You should more carefully verify **what you check** against the existing created dictionary keys.  Can you share a dummy workbook version?

Comment: Are you sure that `umowy(1, 1).Value` isn't an empty string? `dict.Exists(dict.Keys()(0))` will always return `True`. At least, place in the same row `Debug.Print umowy(1, 1), dict.keys()(0)`. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: `dict(umowy(i, 1)) = ...` will use the cell itself as key. Try `dict(umowy(i, 1).value) = ...`

Comment: Or check the cell itself (as an object) against the dictionary key. I mean, try `Debug.print umoy(i,1) Is dict.keys()(0)`. Doesn't it return `True`?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, `umowy(1, 1).Value` is not empty (I'm checking it with `MsgBox`). I will try to create dummy workbook.
@VincentG the problem is my program always satisfies `If Not dict.Exists(umowy(i, 1))` so every of  value from `umowy` "is not in dict yet" which is not true, cause `umowy` has duplicates

Comment: Did you try my last suggestion? I mean `Debug.print umoy(i,1) Is dict.keys()(0)`... What does it return in Immediate Window? **A dictionary can accept an object (Range) as key**! Also try the @Vincent G suggestion. It makes sense, exactly from this point of view...

Comment: @FaneDuru indeed `Debug.print umowy(1,1) Is dict.keys()(0)` prints me `False` while `MsgBox umowy(1,1) = dict.keys()(0)` gives me `True`

Comment: Please, try also `MsgBox umowy(1,1).value = dict.keys()(0).value`, even if it looks strange to you... If it raises an error, the key is not a range.

Comment: `MsgBox umowy(1,1).value = dict.keys()(0).value` returns `True`

I will try your suggestions

Comment: So, your code creates keys **as Range**! If you need the values, you should use `dict.add umowy(i, 1).value, Array(bi(i, 1), irr(i, 1) * bi(i, 1))`... In fact, you should **always** use `rng.Values` not only here. Excel sometimes understands what you need and converts the range to its value, but since a dictionary accepts a range as key, and you pass a range, it takes it as you offer...\

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, it works. Also I had to fix that changing the array in dict you mentioned earlier and everything works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! But Vincent G's suggestion came from the same direction, I think... Regarding the wrong dictionary keys adding... Wrong against your expectation. Sometimes, they are more useful in that way... :)